# installing php-gettext using --with-gettext

Tags: 14.04, php, gettext

At the moment I'm figuring out how to install php gettext on Ubuntu 14.04,

the documentation tells me I should use `--with-gettext http://php.net/manual/en/gettext.installation.php#119139`

and I wonder how am I using the command parameter(flag) 
I'm pretty new to usage of gettext and installation of it.

What I know already is that I need to enable it in the php.ini file

```
extension=gettext.so
```

and add the gettext.ini file with the same line.

I have tried `sudo apt-get install php-gettext` also.

Any help is appreciated :)

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

PHP gettext extension is compiled either as builtin module (in case of php5 packages) or included in phpX.Y-common package as dynamic extension and loaded by default (in case of new coinstallable PHP packages).

There's no need to compile it yourself if you are using prepackaged PHP.

Comment: is that the same with CircleCi's Ubuntu builds ?

Comment: I have no idea about CircleCi's builds, you should ask them. You should explicitly write what packages and environment you are using the question. But why don't you try yourself if the `gettext()` is available.

Comment: And if CircleCi doesn't use Ubuntu packages, then your question is off-topic.